# How to create a tournament bracket with tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

So far, I've built a bracket without the connection lines.[image]

I made this using tailwindcss. I would prefer to keep using tailwind with minimal css. I'm having trouble making connection lines between the boxes. This is an example of what I want:

[image]

I've tried doing many different things and I can't seem to figure it out. Help would be appreciated. This is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="flex">
      <div class="w-72 m-8 text-center text-xl">Quarterfinals Round</div>
      <div class="w-72 m-8 text-center text-xl">Semifinals Round</div>
      <div class="w-72 m-8 text-center text-xl">Final Round</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <div class="flex-col m-4">
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col m-4">
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
      <div class="p-10"></div>
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col m-4">
      <div class="bg-gray-900 w-72 h-20 m-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```